# How to turn DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:0000 to MM/YYYY and keep it as date format and not string

Tags: sql-server

How to turn `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:0000` to `MM/YYYY` and keep it as date format and not string in `MS SQL`

i have tried many options but still did not find the right one.

Comment: Did you mean `DD/MM/YYYY` where the time is not stored?

Comment: i tried many things but did not find to right option

Comment: i mean to see only MM/YYYY without the DD.

Comment: so 28/3/2012 13:01:0000 will be 3/2012 but as date and not string

Comment: What you're talking about is the string representation (formatted) of the stored date value. Where is it you want to see it in that format?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep it as date format"? Something like `DATENAME(mm, yourDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(yyyy, yourDate)` will give you a string representation of your date while leaving it intact

Comment: in MySQL is simple, i just type :to_date (date, 'MM/YYYY) and get results, but in MsSQL its totally deferent

Comment: @JonEgerton - just to run a simple query that will will give me the transaction date as the format i have mentioned

Comment: What on earth does mm/yyyy as a date mean? You're missing one crucial requirement of a date there - the day. If you just want to *display* mm/yyyy then you want a string. If it is not for display then please describe the actual purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you cannot keep date as `mm/yyyy` *as* a `date/datetime`. But you could keep it as a string and also convert when needed back to a date as below.

[Sql-Server Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10424)

```
declare @dt datetime = getdate(),
    @mmyyyy varchar(7)

--To format as mm/yyyy
select @mmyyyy = right(convert(varchar(10), @dt, 103),7)

--To convert back to datetime type from  mm/yyyy varchar
select @mmyyyy [mm/yyyy],
       convert(datetime,'01/'+ @mmyyyy,103) back_To_Date
```